# Within an MVC architecture pattern, does it ever make sense to make a facade for a controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, static, controller, facade

I am currently developing an application which has a service class that needs to post an order to an api and receive a response thats then validate. My question is would it make sense to create a static method on the controller in order to make the api call or create another class with static methods that would then in turn make the api call? So as to not have to instantiate a new controller every time and keep the codebase a bit cleaner?

Comment: how are you expecting the result ,via cal back or in a sync manner?

Comment: Synchronous. Its built with PHP.

Comment: making it static sounds good to me ,if API call is being made frequently

Comment: Thanks vijay! Appreciate the feedback.